# External HDD automatically get back after safe remove

Tags: automount, udev, umount

This is weird!
I use `udisks --detach /dev/sdb` for safely remove my hard disk.
after 2 sec hard drive automatically mounted and nautilus window pops up.

This is output of `udevadm monitor --udev`.

```
UDEV  [67744.241650] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/bsg/7:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [67744.242272] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/scsi_device/7:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [67744.242308] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/scsi_disk/7:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [67744.243365] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [67744.243399] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
UDEV  [67744.243545] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
UDEV  [67744.248425] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:1/bsg/7:0:0:1 (bsg)
UDEV  [67744.248520] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [67744.248566] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [67744.248596] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:1/enclosure/7:0:0:1 (enclosure)
UDEV  [67744.248625] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:1/scsi_device/7:0:0:1 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [67744.248660] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:1/scsi_generic/sg3 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [67744.248689] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/scsi_host/host7 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [67744.252526] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0/7:0:0:1 (scsi)
UDEV  [67744.252563] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7/target7:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [67744.252594] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host7 (scsi)
UDEV  [67744.317378] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [67744.339889] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [67751.203840] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [67751.205913] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [67751.207203] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8 (scsi)
UDEV  [67751.208287] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/scsi_host/host8 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [67752.183035] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [67752.183988] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [67752.184022] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:1 (scsi)
UDEV  [67752.184944] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/scsi_device/8:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [67752.184959] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:1/scsi_device/8:0:0:1 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [67752.185348] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [67752.185365] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:1/scsi_generic/sg3 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [67752.185381] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/bsg/8:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [67752.185392] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host8/target8:0:0/8:0:0:0/scsi_disk/8:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [67755.138374] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
UDEV  [67755.140810] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.
```

As you see, HDD detach from system and after that come back to system again. Kernel add this device after i removed it.

Any idea appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is no solution! It is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/792085) and no solution suggested up to now :(.

I've researched about `udev` rules and i got nothing.
Fortunately, this problem does not exist in Ubuntu 10.04.